# SQL Query, What have I done wrong? I am fairly new to mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhT01.png)
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2qNx.png)

```
SELECT agency_name, Count(*) AS complaint_type_count
FROM service_request_xs
GROUP BY agency_name
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

- solution uploaded

Comment: Count() needs an argument, if you like to count all grouped rows use count(*). You can't order by an aggregate function, for this you should use HAVING Clause

Comment: So, this last edit by nicael also changed the code. Did the code contain the * or not...?

Comment: Yes, it does containt (*), unsure why it didn't pop up. Photo to help on problem

Comment: @Hazza Show us your result please.

Comment: @Stoff if you click on the "edited x minutes ago" link you can see the edit history

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT compliant_type)`, not `COUNT(*)`  See the answer by Samuel or Stoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell the count() function what to count. You can insert an individual column, or * for all of it etc. But you have to count something.

This is a fiddle, showing how it works:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dbPnE4BXv8oRRkQY4WQs8v/1

```
SELECT agency_name, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT compliant_type) AS complaint_type_count
FROM service_request_xs
GROUP BY agency_name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT compliant_type) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you use the `Count()` function, you have to add a column name between the parentheses; such as: `Count(complaint_type)` or else SQL will not know what to count.

You have to do this in the `SELECT` and the `ORDER BY`.

You can also use `Count(*)` to count all lines in your table.